# Create MD5 hash list of big memory mapped files

Tags: c#, performance, hashcode

I wrote this class:

```
public class MediaFile : IDisposable
{

    private const int SECTION_SIZE = 8192;

    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public List<byte[]> Checksums { get; private set; }

    private FileInfo fileInfo;
    private MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile;

    public MediaFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"{filePath} was not found!");

        this.FilePath = filePath;
        this.Checksums = null;

        this.fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        this.memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        this.Checksums = this.GenerateChecksums();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.memoryMappedFile.Dispose();
    }

    public byte[] Read(long offset, int size)
    {
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream memoryMappedViewStream = this.memoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream(offset, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryMappedViewStream))
            return binaryReader.ReadBytes(size);
    }

    private List<byte[]> GenerateChecksums()
    {
        List<byte[]> checksums = new List<byte[]>();

        double sectionsCalc = this.fileInfo.Length / (double) SECTION_SIZE;

        long normalSizedSectionCount = (long) Math.Floor(sectionsCalc);
        int lastSectionSize = (int) ((sectionsCalc - normalSizedSectionCount) * (double) SECTION_SIZE);

        using (MD5 hashProvider = MD5.Create())
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < normalSizedSectionCount; i++)
                checksums.Add(hashProvider.ComputeHash(this.Read(i * SECTION_SIZE, SECTION_SIZE)));

            checksums.Add(hashProvider.ComputeHash(this.Read(normalSizedSectionCount * SECTION_SIZE, lastSectionSize)));
        }

        return checksums;
    }

}
```

The purpose of this class is to read large media files and create md5 hashes (checksums in this case) for all x bytes (`SECTION_SIZE`) of the file and add them to a list.

I want to know if there is a better/faster way to accomplish this.

Comment: If "faster" is a goal then why are you using a crypto-strength hash? Remember, crypto strength hashes are more secure when they are **slower**.  You want an attacker to have to do a lot of work to break a hash. If all you want is a checksum then why are you not using an algorithm specifically designed for checksums, like CRC?

Answer (score 2):

- You named your class `MediaFile` but basically its a class which creates checksums for any given file. You should consider to rename the class to e.g `ChecksumCreator` of `FileChecksumCreator`. This would make the purpose and the responsibility of that class obvious by looking at its name.
- Omitting braces `{}` although they might be optional can lead to serious bugs which aren't tracked easily. I would like to encourage you to always use them.
- You are using C# 6 but you still use `private` setters for your properties. With C# 6 you can just omit them if you either set the proerties at startup or from inside of the constructor. The backing field of a getter only property is internally handled as `readonly` and because you only set them inside the constructor you should take this route. While we are at the constructor, you are first assigning `null` to the `Checksums` property and later on you are using the `GenerateChecksums()` method to assign a value to it. The mentioned points could be implemented like so

  ```
  public string FilePath { get; }
  public List<byte[]> Checksums { get; }

  private FileInfo fileInfo;
  private MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile;

  public MediaFile(string filePath)
  {
      if (!File.Exists(filePath))
      {
          throw new FileNotFoundException($"{filePath} was not found!");
      }

      this.FilePath = filePath;

      this.fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
      this.memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open);

      this.Checksums = this.GenerateChecksums();
  }
  ```

  But basically, you won't need a `FileInfo` object here, because you are only using the `Length` property of the `FileInfo` object. So let us change this like so

  ```
  public string FilePath { get; }
  public List<byte[]> Checksums { get; }

  private long fileLength;
  private MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile;

  public MediaFile(string filePath)
  {
      if (!File.Exists(filePath))
      {
          throw new FileNotFoundException($"{filePath} was not found!");
      }

      this.FilePath = filePath;

      this.fileLength= new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
      this.memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open);

      this.Checksums = this.GenerateChecksums();
  }
  ```

  But what happens if you decide later on to go the way @EricLippert has shown in the comments, like using a `CRC` hashprovider to generate the checksums ? You would need to change the class in question. Maybe it would be better to inject a `HashAlgorithm` provider so you could easily switch to another one.

  This would result in an overloaded constructor and a slightly changed `Dispose()` method like so

  ```
  private bool hasOwnershipOfHashprovider = false;
  private HashAlgorithm hashProvider;

  public MediaFile(string filePath)
      : this(filePath, MD5.Create())
  {
      hasOwnershipOfHashprovider = true;
  }
  public MediaFile(string filePath, HashAlgorithm hashProvider)
  {
      if (!File.Exists(filePath))
      {
          throw new FileNotFoundException($"{filePath} was not found!");
      }
      if (hashProvider == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException($"hashProvider");
      }

      this.FilePath = filePath;

      this.hashProvider = hashProvider;
      this.fileLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
      this.memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open);

      this.Checksums = this.GenerateChecksums();
  }


  public void Dispose()
  {
      this.memoryMappedFile.Dispose();
      if (this.hasOwnershipOfHashprovider)
      {
          this.hashProvider.Dispose();
      }
  }
  ```

  But what happens if the user of that class won't call `Dispose()` ? Take a look at [proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/2655508).
- I don't see why the `Read()` method should be public. If it needs to be public, you should add some proper validation of the passed arguments.
- If a `filePath` is passed to the constructor which represents a file with `Length == 0` the `MemoryMappedFikle.Create()` method will throw an `ArgumentException` which should better be thrown by your code.